# Element UI with VueJS Autocomplete : Avoid Mutation A Props (Vue Warn)

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, prop, element-ui

I have a big problem with VueJS and Element UI https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#autocomplete-attributes
I use the AutoComplete Component, and i want that I click on the input (onFocus Event), my suggestions re appear

```
<el-autocomplete
            id="inputID"
            name="inputName"
            class="inputClass"
            v-model="inputModel"
            :fetch-suggestions="querySearchInput"
            placeholder= "Select an Input"
            ref="inputReference"
            value-key="id"
            v-loading="inputLoader"
            :value="inputValue"
            @select="onChangeInput"
            @focus="onFocusInput"
            @clear="onClearInput"
            clearable
        >
            <!-- Slot : Override Component Suggestions -->
            <template slot-scope="{item}" v-if="item.id">
                {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
            </template>
        </el-autocomplete>
```

on my onFocus or onClear i used :

```
this.inputModel = "";
this.inputValue = ""
```

But it does not reset my suggestions.. :/
The only way for me is to use :

```
 this.$refs.inputReference.value = "";
```

But it's not a best pratice I have a message :  " vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"  "

I use a :value and a v-model on my component because i stock an ID but i display a label with i18n, isn't important

VERY THANKS YOU

I think it's because the AutoComplete Component includes a InputComponent, and i'm not a pro with the cascading prop on VueJS..

Thanks.

Comment: PS : The link of the component : 

https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/autocomplete/src/autocomplete.vue

Answer (score 1):

Just do like it says. Do not mutate props. If you need to change some date from props, save it to local component data and modify it

```html
props: {
  foo: {
      type: number,
      requred: true
    }
},

...

data () {
  return {
    localFoo: this.foo
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm not on personal component. I have a component El-autocomplete that call an input in its own code, i don't have access

Comment: Oh, I get it. You using `value` binding and `v-model`, that's incorrect. `v-model='foo'` basically means `:value='foo', @change='updateFoo'`. So you prob need to del `:value` and left only `v-model`. Here is [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to that info.